# Let the function $f(x)=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ such that :$4(1+x^2)f''(x)+4x f'(x)=f(x)$

Tags: functions, derivatives

Let the function $$f(x)=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$ such that :$4(1+x^2)f''(x)+4x f'(x)=f(x)$

1)Prove that we can choose the number $A$ such that the function $g$ definied on $[0,\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}]$ as following:
$$g(t)=\frac{1}{2} f(2t)-f(t)+\frac{1}{2} -A \frac{t^2}{2}$$ verifies the conditions of Rolle's theorem

2) Prove that: $\exists c \in ]0,\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}[$ $: A=f''(c)$

I tried to apply condition of Rolle theorem on $g$ but i think that i'm wrong